# Add custom ransacker that uses scope with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm using [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) gem and I have a model that has a scope like this:

```
scope :by_attr, ->(attr) {
  case attr
  when val1
    query1
  when val2
    query2
  else
    all
  end
}
```

I can't figure out, how can I write a ransacker that uses this scope. For example, I want this behavior:

```
MyModel.search(by_attr: val1) # should return MyModel.query1
MyModel.search(by_attr: val2) # should return MyModel.query2
```

Anyone has some thoughts about that?

Answer (score 5):

There is an extract, from the https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/288:

In your model:

```
scope :by_name, ->(name) {
  where name: name
}

def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
  [:by_name]
end
```

In your view (according to https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#ransacks-search_form_for-helper-replaces-form_for-for-creating-the-view-search-form):

```
= search_form_for @q do |f|
  = f.search_field :by_name, value, [['Value 1', val1], ['Value 2', val2]]
```

To avoid using explicit array while creating forms use different helpers, such as `options_from_collection_for_select`.

You might write `MyModel.ransack(by_name: value).results` in your code as well.

Comment: You made my day. I had finding it 2 years, and finally I found it!

To use it with ActiveAdmin do something like:

    scope :by_name_eq, ->(name) { where(name: name) }

    def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
      [:by_name_eq]
    end

    # In AA 
    filter :by_name_eq

and it use scope as Ransack filter!

Comment: Yup. I can confirm that this worked for me too. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has a problem like mine there is an interesting PR in ransack that allows to use scopes as keys in `search` method: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/288